# Finding Manager for LDAP user

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I want be able to find who is a manager for a specific user. I have no idea of where to start. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manager` property of the associated user object is the `DN` of the user object that represents the manager of the user.

Comment: How can i find data like sub-department...?

Answer (score 3):

You need to know what your LDAP path is for your user - if you have no idea, you might want to download my LDAP browser [BeaverTail](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html).

[image]

Once you know what your user's LDAP path looks like, it's pretty easy: bind to that user by means of its LDAP path, and grab it's `Manager` property:

```
DirectoryEntry deUser = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=John Doe,cn=Users,dc=YourCorp,dc=com");

if(deUser != null)
{
   // check if the manager property is set - it could be NULL (no manager defined)
   if(deUser.Properties["manager"] != null)
   {
      string managerDN = deUser.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
   }
}
```

That `Manager` property again contains a "distinguished name" (DN) - i.e. an LDAP path - for the manager's `DirectoryEntry`.